# C fork and pipe multiple process

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement this command `cat /etc/passwd | grep 1000 | cut -d: -f1` in C using system calls fork and pipe.
When I use only two commands `cmd1 | cmd2` so 1 fork it works fine but when I'm using more than 2 process the problem occurs
Here is my code, I think the problem is in the grand parent block

**Update** :
I closed some unclosed file descriptors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(){
    int fd[2], fd2[2];
    pid_t pid, pid2;
    char str[100];

    if(pipe(fd) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error pipe.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(pipe(fd2) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error pipe.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    do{
        pid = fork();
    }while(pid == -1 && errno == EAGAIN);

    if(pid == -1){
        perror("fork()");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pid == 0){
        pid2 = fork();
        if(pid2 == 0){
            // fprintf(stderr, "1 - Grand Child\n");
            close(fd[0]);
            dup2(fd[1], 1);
            close(fd[1]);
            execlp("cat", "cat", "/etc/passwd", NULL);
            perror("cat error");
        }else{
            wait(&pid2);
            // fprintf(stderr, "2 - Child\n");
            close(fd[1]);
            dup2(fd[0], 0);
            close(fd[0]);

            up2(fd2[1], 1);
            close(fd2[1]);

            execlp("grep", "grep", "1000", NULL);
            perror("grep failed");
        }
        return 1;
    }else{
        wait(&pid);
        // fprintf(stderr, "3 - Parent\n");
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd2[0], 0);
        close(fd2[0]);
        execlp("cut", "cut", "-d:", "-f1", NULL);
        perror("cut failed");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that this is not the main question, but you can replace `cat /etc/passwd | grep 1000 | cut -d: -f1`, with `grep 1000 /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1`. These two are equivalent, this would also affect your C implementation. Furthermore, what you are trying to implement could be done without calling any external processes, but I guess there is some rationale for doing it the way you did (exercise or something).

Comment: Yep I know, but what I'm trying to achieve is to use pipe and fork with more than 2 commands

Comment: @tomix86 I'm learning system programing

Comment: Without looking at any details, gut instinct says "you're leaving file descriptors open".  Looking at your code, that is confirmed.  The template is `dup2(fd, 0); close(fd)`.  You need to close the descriptor you just dup'd.

Comment: And you need to close a lot more than that.  If you open 2 pipes, then you have 7 total open file descriptors.  Each child should have only 3 when you call exec.  If you call dup, then you are up to 8.  So you need to call close 5 times before you exec.  This is true in every child.

Comment: (But you get a close for free when you dup if you don't close the 2nd argument first.)

Comment: I did as you said but nothing happened

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. There isn't even a problem description here.

Comment: You're calling `wait` in your parent processes. Cool deadlock.

Comment: Even without `wait` it gives the same problem

Comment: You probably aren't closing enough file descriptors. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both ends of the pipe as soon as possible. That means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions. It includes [`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD` too.

Comment: when fork fails it can raise to error `EAGAIN` and `ENOMEM`, the first one `EAGAIN` tells that there is no place in the process table and the second one tells that the kernel had no more memory

Comment: You shouldn't wait before running the `cut`; you should (close file descriptors and) execute `cut` immediately.   If you want to wait for the children to die before executing, you create a third child which launches the `cut`, while the parent waits in a loop before executing.

Comment: So I remove the wait from both parent and child ?

Comment: Your second child is still not closing either side of `fd2` before it execs.  Close everything that you're not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close all unused file descriptors in both children and parents! In this case, when using dup2(), all file descriptors associated with pipes may be closed.

For clarity I used macros for file descriptors associated with stdin and stdout. Macros STDIN_FILENO and STDOUT_FILENO are declared in unistd.h.

Waiting for children (`wait(&pid);` and `wait(&pid2);`) is not needed. You do not need to wait for `cat` to end before running `grep`, as grep will process them as they come. Pipe should have a big buffer, like 65536 bytes, so after cat command ends data will be buffered in pipe, but it is not something to count on.

The following code, with only minor changes, works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(){
    int fd[2], fd2[2];
    pid_t pid, pid2;
    char str[100];

    if(pipe(fd) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error pipe.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(pipe(fd2) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error pipe.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    do{
        pid = fork();
    }while(pid == -1 && errno == EAGAIN);

    if(pid == -1){
        perror("fork()");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pid == 0){
        pid2 = fork();
        if(pid2 == 0){
            // fprintf(stderr, "1 - Grand Child\n");
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO); // 1);
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            close(fd2[1]);
            close(fd2[0]);

            execlp("cat", "cat", "/etc/passwd", NULL);
            perror("cat error");
        }else{
            // wait(&pid2);
            // fprintf(stderr, "2 - Child\n");
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO); //0);
            dup2(fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO); // 1);
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            close(fd2[1]);
            close(fd2[0]);

            execlp("grep", "grep", "1000", NULL);
            perror("grep failed");
        }
        return 1;
    }else{
        // wait(&pid);
        // fprintf(stderr, "3 - Parent\n");
        dup2(fd2[0], STDIN_FILENO); //0);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        close(fd2[1]);
        close(fd2[0]);

        execlp("cut", "cut", "-d:", "-f1", NULL);
        perror("cut failed");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You said "Waiting for children is not needed", which is accurate, but the criterion is actually stronger than that.  It is crucial, in general, that the code does not wait for the children as you may very well get blockages because one process generates more data than can fit in the pipe buffer (which was historically 5 KiB; POSIX only requires 4 KiB; but many modern O/S use 64 KiB).  Also, because the parent hasn't closed file descriptors when waiting, the processes can be deadlocked if the parent waits.